# $routeChangeSuccess inside directive doesn't fire

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive placed in my navigation header. The point of it is to add/remove the active class. It does this by hooking into $routeChangeSuccess and looking at the anchors where the href is the route name.

```
angular.module('frApp')
    .directive('bsActiveLink', ['$location', function ($location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A', //use as attribute 
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, elem) {
                //after the route has changed
                scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
                    console.log("Route changed");

                    var hrefs = ['/#' + $location.path(),
                    '#' + $location.path(), //html5: false
                        $location.path()]; //html5: true

                    angular.forEach(elem.find('a'), function (a) {
                        a = angular.element(a);
                        if (-1 !== hrefs.indexOf(a.attr('href'))) {
                            a.parent().addClass('active');
                        } else {
                            a.parent().removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


div class="col-3" style="vertical-align: middle;" bs-active-link>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/unpaid">Unpaid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/paid">Paid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/recon">Recon</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The main issue is this event doesn't get called on initial load. Now normally that's not an issue as you can see I set one as default and I have the angularjs routing redirect to this. But if I place another route directly into the address bar it'll load that one but visually the default '/unpaid' route has the active class on it. If I remove the default active class in the html then nothing is active. I'm seeing that my $routeChangeSuccess isn't hooked yet when the page loads.

It would seem to me that directives couldn't rely on this event hook on startup? What's the workaround to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
link: function (scope, elem) {
    function update(...) {}
    // just call here
    update();
    scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", update);
```

P.S. Such directives do not follow angular ideas. As an example why it is bad - if at some point new  element appears in DOM - it wont be covered by directive. E.g. look at ui-router and u will see how this should be done:

```
~something like this~~
<div>
   <a href="/unpaid" my-active-if="unpaid">... // <- custom directive on each href, sp no weird find required
   <a href="/paid" my-active-if="paid">...
```